# Numbering subappendices by number instead of letter

Tags: numbering, appendices, appendix

I am using package appendix to manage several subappendices within each chapter of my thesis, but I would like all my appendixes to be denoted by A and numbered by number instead of by letter.
E.g.: In chapter 2 I would like them to be:
2.A.1
2.A.2
2.A.3
...
instead of:
2.A
2.B
2.C
...

My main file looks like:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%to manage multiple appendices
\usepackage{appendix}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
...
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables

%include Abstract to the table of contents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\include{chapters/abstract}

%\chapter{Introduction}
\include{chapters/introduction}

%\chapter{First paper}
\include{chapters/chapter02}

%\chapter{Second paper}
\include{chapters/chapter03}

%\chapter{Conclusion}
\include{chapters/conclusion}

\end{document}
```

and each chapter looks like:

```
\chapter{...}
\section{...}
\section{...}
...
\pagebreak

\begin{subappendices}
\section{...}
\section{...}
...
\end{subappendices}
```

Comment: Have you considered something like `\begin{subappendices} \section{Appendices to Chapter N} \subsection{...} \subsection{...} \subsection{...} \end{subappendices}`?

Comment: that was helpful, thank you!